# Kali linux faild apt update

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

I'm running an Azure Linux VM and every time I try to `sudo update` it gives me an error like that (the spaces in `http. kali.or` are just for my reps):

```
E: Failed to fetch http://http. kali.org/kali/pool/main/....2-2_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http. kali.org/kali/pool/main/....2-2_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http. kali.org/kali/pool/main/....2-2_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http. kali.org/kali/pool/main/....2-2_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http. kali.org/kali/pool/main/....2-2_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http. kali.org/kali/pool/main/....7-3_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http. kali.org/kali/pool/main/....7-3_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http. kali.org/kali/pool/main/....1-2_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http. kali.org/kali/pool/main/....1-2_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http. kali.org/kali/pool/main/....1-2_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http. kali.org/kali/pool/main/....1-2_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http. kali.org/kali/pool/main/...0kali1_all.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Is there really a space in `http://http. kali.org`?  If so then something is screwed up in `/etc/sources.list` because this shouldn't have spaces like that.

Comment: What do you mean for *the spaces in http. kali.or are just for my reps*?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` (and ev. the directory with similar name).

It seems you edited some file and you forgot about it. It would much simpler if you test things when you edit file, so you know the cause of errors (and you should also write in the question).

In this case, it seems that `http://http. kali.org/kali/` is a copy/paste error. Are you sure about the address? In the question you added a space after the point, and possibly you should use `https:` (some software now complain about not using a secure connection). And check what it is in the three dots. You can check the URL on your browser (maybe you are using an obsolete version, which it is not more available on your local mirror).

And such errors are not show in case of `update` (update will not download .deb packages). Are you confusing `update` with `upgrade` and so are you using the second without using the first command?